# Data exchange between a service and an activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity, progress-bar

I have to publish the progress from a background service on the UI continuously on a progress bar. Any ideas on how to go about it. Intents won't work I guess coz they can only send the data once the activity is started. Ant other suggestions?

Update : The progress on the UI happens on a progress Bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help mice, but since I needed to update progress bars on different activities in my app depending on which one was visible, I found it easier to implement through Broadcast Intents and Recievers and Intent Filters. All I had to do was to Broadcast the progress in my service wrapped up in a bundle via a broadcast Intent (with a custom Intent Filter applied) and register (in onResume()) an inner subclass of BroadcastReciever in the activities which needed the progress (having the same intent filter). One can also unregister these recievers in the onPause() method of the activity to save memory headspace.

Comment: is this recommended approach/pattern for this kind a communication betweet service and activity?

Answer (score 1):

Extend Application, which is created once for entire application.

When Activity starts, store its reference to a field in your Application object. (Note that you can access Application using Activity.getApplication). Set this field to Activity reference or null in onPause/onResume calls.

Then in Service, you have also access to your Application by Service.getApplication. So look if your Activity reference is non-null, meaning that your Activity is shown to user, and update UI as needed in such case, by calling methods on your Activity.

Comment: Ok.. how to publish that progress on a progess bar which is there in that activity? Would setProgress() work?

Comment: I mean Activity.setProgress()

Comment: Certainly this is good option. Just make sure to call requestWindowFeature to enable title progress bar.

Comment: And how do you set the title progress bar to the pre-defined one in the layout?

Comment: Try to ask another question about progress bars. Comments are not ideal for discussing different task.

Comment: If you write to a variable non-null value, then it should be written.

Comment: I had a subclass of Application. In it I created a static Activity object of the required activity and set that reference to 'this' in the onCreate() and onResume() methods of the activity and to null in th onPause() method. Still when I am retireving that reference in another activity by ApplicationClass.ActivityInstance it is returning null all the time even when the activity is visible. Did I so something wrong there?

Comment: First problem, you can'tt create Activity, system creates it from an Intent.

Comment: You certainly seem to think I am that dumb do you? Of course activities are created through intents, But every activity is a class basically and objects of a class can be created . It is like :  private MyActivity MyActivityObject;